# How to integrate ajax responses from backend to jquery validator?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, validation

I am getting a json response from my server:

```
{"success":false,"register_email":"","register_firstname":"","register_lastname":"<p>Please enter last name.<\/p>","register_password":"<p>Please enter your password.<\/p>","register_repeat_password":"<p>Please retype your password.<\/p>","register_about":"<p>Enter atleast 50 characters long.<\/p>"}
```

Now, I need to show these errors in my html page using jquery validator.

```
<div class="form-group">
                            <label for="lastname" class="col-md-3 control-label">Last Name</label>
                            <div class="col-md-9">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="register_lastname" placeholder="Last Name">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="password" class="col-md-3 control-label">Password</label>
                            <div class="col-md-9">
                                <input type="password" class="form-control"  id="register_password" name="register_password" placeholder="Password">
                            </div>
                        </div>
```

In case of front-end check, I am successfully using jquery validator.

```
$('#signupform').validate({
        rules: {
            register_email: {
                required:true,
                email:true
            },
            register_firstname: "required",
            register_lastname: "required",
            register_password: {
                required:true,
                minlength:6
            },
            register_repeat_password: {
                required:true,
                equalTo: "#register_password"
            },
            register_about: {
                required:true,minlength:50
            },

        },
        messages: {
            register_email: "Please Enter your email.",
            register_firstname: "Enter your first name",
            register_lastname: "Enter your last name.",
            register_password: {
                required: "Please enter your password.",
                minlength: "Your password should be of minimum 8 characters."
            },
            register_repeat_password: {
                required: "Please retype your password",
                equalTo: "Your password don't match."
            },
            register_about: "Please Enter at least 50 characters."          
        },
        errorElement: 'div',
        errorClass: 'alert alert-danger fade in',
```

I want to achieve the same in case of backend check.

I googled, I came to know about `remote` attribute in jquery validator, but it works for only one field, at a time. I want to integrate backend responses in each and every case.

Comment: Can you share the code that contains remote attribute ?
+ Check this https://jqueryvalidation.org/remote-method/

Comment: I didn't try that. Look, I want to show jquery validation from backend response for all my fields, not only a few.